# Android studio's design view and gradle not working

Tags: android-studio

Everything I add to my design view goes to the top right corner and is so small that it is not visible and causing error also I have installed all the sdk's but still it is so frustrating that it is failing to compile gradle

Comment: The code is computer generated and not edited by me :|

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.